# How do I find the root component of a given component in zk?

Tags: java, zk

In my viewmodel I have the following code:

```
@Command
public void onFinish(@BindingParam(value = "myButton") Button myButton) {
        Component root = myButton.getParent().getParent().getParent();
        ...
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to find the root component of any given component? The expression above has to be altered every time I change the zul.

P.S. I am new to zkoss..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your root component has an id, you could do the following:

```
Component root = myButton.getPage().getFellow("id-of-root-component");
```

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what the root of your component is.

Your root is normally an `IdSpace`, and if you didn't have set other IdSpace element's you could use :

```
@Command
public void onFinish(@ContextParam(ContextType.SPACE_OWNER) IdSpace spaceOwner) {

    ...
}
```

This way, you never have to pass anything in the zul.
It will automaticly fetch that component.
Remember that `IdSpace` is an interface what is implemented in some specific components.

[Please take a look of the other](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/syntax/contextparam.html), maybe more suitable in your case, options you can do.

But there are [also other tricks](https://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/syntax/selectorparam.html), this one uses CSS selectors :

```
@Command
public void onFinish(@SelectorParam(":root") Component root) {
    ...
}
```

Like this you will always have the root.

I'm not a great fan of sending components from the view to the viewmodel with bindingparams.
Reason is that today, you call this command from a button, but maybe you add the same command on other component and then this will fail.
Yes, you can use the `Component` class, but MVVM has so many ways to do it in a better way without polluting your view.
Remember that the whole point of MVVM is a separation between UI and code.
It may not matter what triggers a command, even as it doesn't matter what your collection will fill on the screen.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you explain to me what this code does? The problem with this line `Component root = myButton.getParent().getParent().getParent();` is that if I change the zul, e.g. add another div element to it, I might have to add another call to getParent(). So far, I do not see how your solution changes that. The code suggested by @Matthias works in my situation.

Comment: Also, the official zk documentation is somewhat unhelpful in these situations. The code snippets presented there are usually not sufficient to understand the entire context of how a particular framework feature is supposed to be used....in my humble opinion...:)

Comment: Ow sorry, copied your code and altered the main method. You don't need to call getParent anymore, added also the use of css selectors as a better solution

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you. I see your point now. :) Your solution will keep the view "cleaner".